# IE9 gives different lay-out results for same page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, intranet

I have a development environment for WordPress based on Windows 2012 R2 with some theme in Microsoft Azure.

If I deploy it to production which is also Windows 2012 R2 but in a local data center, it looks perfect the same on IE 11 and Google Chrome.

But on the client which has IE 9, the production (local) site is displayed different then the remote Development one. Menu's are different displayed.

When I compare the source (and replace the URL with a similar name) there's no difference between the two. So why is IE 9 rendering the local production site different?

I even searched for cases like one of the images is maybe harded linked to the development site, but that is not the case.

So, the only difference I can think of is that the production site has some name like :

http://Intranet/

versus

http://devintranet.cloudapp.net/

Could that be a difference in security settings local versus internet (which I cannot see from client perspective). And strange thing is that the Internet version is corrent and the local intranet version is different.

I have really no clue where to search for answers.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a CSS issue?

Comment: Can you share site url?

Comment: Hi mevius, the only difference the both pages have is the URL. When using Chrome or IE 11 both pages look exactly the same, on IE 9 the sources are the same, so they use the same CSS code. All the files are the same and the WordPress database is the same, except that the production URL name is used instead of development url.

Comment: Arshad, sorry I cannot, it's behind firewall and production is behind a proxy and does not have public access.

Comment: Mevius, what would be the possible explanations of CSS issue? a hardlink to something on development? Or a change between intranet IP addresses and Internet IP addresses?

Comment: Could it be an IIS setting on the production server?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution....

IE9 was automatically adding intranet sites tot compatibility mode. It's a setting : Menu Tools > Compatibility view settings. Removing the intranet from the list and uncheck the box which was the default setting.

Why does MS put Intranet sites automatically in compatibility mode?? It has cost me hours and frustration.